# error: non-static method setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-webview

i tried to build a web view app from scratch and as i am new to this i was facing error on line 22, as i set websetting.setjavascriptenabled(true); it didnt accept.

error popup

```
error: non-static method setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context
        WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

my project settings is for android Oreo 8.1

```
package net.jptechsolutions.jptechinvoice;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView mywebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
    WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mywebview.loadUrl("https://*********************");

    mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mywebview.canGoBack())
    {
        mywebview.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: use `webSettings` instead of `WebSettings`

Comment: `WebSettings` is class name, while `webSettings` is variable name. `setJavaScriptEnabled` is not static, therefore you can't call it from the class name, only from a variable name

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

instead of

```
 WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

You are using Class name with method name. Use the object name defined by you with the method name.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help and what if i wan to download files from the sites that is opened by my app , what should i add or to edit

Comment: Try this.

mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

Comment: thank for ur reply ...idk somehow i did it but now i am facing something new ..can u check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216795/force-close-error-after-downloading-file-from-app

Answer (score 0):

You call the static function of WebSettings. It should be: `webSettings. setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`